Data Protection API (DPAPI) : what algorithm is used to encrypt the data
In document only mentioned that "It provides protection using the user or machine credentials to encrypt or decrypt data." but there is no explanation about what algorithm is used to encrypt the data like ASE 256 etc..
Link to documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata?view=net-8.0
Could anyone clarify the encryption algorithm used by ProtectedData? Knowing the specific algorithm would be very helpful.
Thanks.
